# Reledmac/Reledpar: killing unwanted indents

Tags: indentation, reledmac, reledpar

Very simple question. I just need to kill all the indents after every \pstart.

I already tried with things like \noindent, \hspace, etc. with no effect. I read that indents go with language, and here I have italian and greek.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside, openright]{book}%openany

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\unicodefont{Garamond Premier Pro}  
\newfontfamily\ItalicFont{Garamond Premier Pro}
\newfontfamily\SlantedFont{Garamond Premier Pro}
\setmainfont[Ligatures      = TeX, 
            Numbers         = OldStyle,
            Contextuals=NoAlternate
            ]{Garamond Premier Pro}         
\newfontfamily\greekfont{Garamond Premier Pro}
\usepackage{polyglossia}                        
    \setmainlanguage{italian}
    \setotherlanguage[variant=ancient,numerals=arabic]{greek}           

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% COMANDI RELEDMAC / RELEDPAR %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[noledgroup,                                 % Escludo l'uso di note dentro minipage
            noeledsec,                                  % Non uso comandi di sezionamento tipo chapter, section, etc all'interno del txt critico
            series={A,B}]{reledmac}                     % Restringo le serie di note alle sole che uso
\usepackage[shiftedpstarts, nomaxlines]{reledpar}            % settaggi di sincronia. % advancedshiftedpstarts


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% INIZIO DOCUMENTO %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{greek}  
\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\numberpstarttrue
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{2}
\pstart 
Ἐν πολλοῖς μέν εἰσιν οἱ ἔλεγχοι \edtext{πολυστίχοις}{\Afootnote{πολιστίχοις Ma}} \edtext{ἐσπαρμένοι}{\Afootnote{ἐπαρμένοι FP ἐγκατεσπαρμένοι J}} λόγοις, δι’ ὧν ἡ ὀφρὺς κατασπᾶται τῶν τὴν ἀλήθειαν ἐν ἀδικίᾳ κατέχειν φιλονεικούντων. \pend

\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\selectlanguage{italian}        
\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\numberpstarttrue
\normalsize
\pstart
I want to kill all these indents, please. Poiché dunque la tua ricerca, magnifica e cara a Dio, ha richiesto una sinossi degli argomenti per farne uno schema, \edtext{cosa}{\Bendnote{Prova per vedere se il numero è corretto}} per noi gradita alla divina provvidenza, vedrai che tale obiettivo non indegno del tuo amor di Dio né della tua richiesta sarà perseguito.\pend

\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages              


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want any paragraph indention in you document, you can use the "parskip" package to use vertical space between paragraphs instead.
You can also suppress all indents without using parskip instead by setting the paragaph indent to zero with

```
\parindent=0pt
```

at the end of your preamble. You can also use this inside a group, then it will only act locally:
For example if it comes after `\begin{pages}`, te effect will only last until `\end{pages}`.

You should do this only in combination with another paragraph mark like your numbering, otherwise you can no longer discern the paragraphs.

Comment: Not in every part of may document. Before the critical edition I have a long essay in which I'm using the \indentfirst. Is there a way to kill just the ones loaded after every \pstart?

Comment: For instance I tried: \AtEveryPstart{\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}} but it doesn't work

Comment: @Teodoro I haven't found a way to do this, but I added how you can restrict the scope of this change. It also can be restricted with `{\parindent=0pt\relax <All your code without indent here>}`.